# putty ssh client tuturial?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, command

i really wanted to learn about using linux commands, so i can access my remote server, i wanted a good tuturial on how i can use this once for all, before i used always avoid it figure its important to learn if im going to be using a linux server. any good tuturial you know where i can start learning commands,

p.s. i have installed putty, if that it means anything :)) thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=learn+linux

Comment: Start here maybe http://linuxcommand.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My copy of "Unix for Programmers and Users" was much loved by the people I lent it to, until it didn't make it back after falling apart from so much use.  That was the first edition, there's now a third edition.